# Coda 2 - RegEx - Search and Replace Issues

Tags: coda

I'm trying to search and replace links in over 400 HTML pages. Pretty much I need to change:

Search: domain-name[dot]org/learning/bridge.php?sl=**70** 
Replace:
Replace: seconddomainname[dot]com/Water/**70**.htm

Pretty much search for link1 and replace using link2 but keeping the number from link1. The regular expression (link included below) worked but when I apply it to Coda 2, it doesn't work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwTTT.png)

Answer (score 2):

Is actually quite simple. You don't need to escape anything in your search string aside for the question mark and period.

Your search is:

```
http://domain-name\.org/learning/bridge\.php\?sl=([\d]+)
```

and your replace is:

```
http://new-domain/water/\1.htm
```